# Drupal password hash not matching existing hash

Tags: php, drupal, encryption, hash, sha

When logging into a Drupal instance (Drupal 7.22) I've set up, I keep getting a invalid username/password error. I've tried changing passwords and other users to no avail.

What's especially odd is that I'm able to log in to the same Drupal instance when it's running on other servers (it connects to a remote database). The two computers I've been able to log in successfully have both been Linux machines, vs. the one that doesn't work (OS X running MAMP). The code base is also the same.

I did some debugging and found that the hash that's created on login to verify isn't the same as the one stored in the database. I got down to the `_password_itoa64` method in `password.inc`, and gave up trying to debug the individual character matches.

Has anyone encountered anything similar, or have any idea why the hashes would be different?

Comment: I think it would be better if you post it on Drupal support forum.

Comment: Too little information: 1. What version of Drupal 2. What is the hash, generated for the password on bad and good machines? 3. Did you try to call function user_check_password on both systems, comparing the result?

Comment: try to copy the hashed password from the working copy and replace it with the none working copy.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is in different PHP versions. Older versions (5.2 or 5.3 AFAIK) had week hash algorithm in "crypt" module, later it was updated.